# Delete index session in PHP

Tags: php, session

I have question referring to the session in PHP.

I've coded in PHP for setting the session and I want to delete it , but I got some errors and confusing with using the UNSET(variable $_SESSION). Perhaps anyone could help me to show what should I do with this matter. Thanks in advance

```
                    $_SESSION['chart'] = array();
                    $_SESSION['chart'][0]['index']  = 0
                    $_SESSION['chart'][0]['type'] = $type;
                    $_SESSION['chart'][0]['idanimal'] = $iddog;
                    $_SESSION['chart'][0]['price'] = $price;
                    printdata(); // <== this is the function to print out the data
```

All I want to do is just delete based on the index in this session

Here's the function  :

```
function printdata()
                {
                    $totalharga = 0;
                    if(is_array($_SESSION['chart']))
                    {
                    echo "<h3>"."Berikut adalah keranjang belanja anda" . "</h3>". "<br>";
                    $max = count($_SESSION['chart']);  
                    $th1 = "<th>" . "No" . "</th>";
                    $th2 = "<th>" . "Animal Type" . "</th>";
                    $th3 = "<th>" . "ID Binatang" . "</th>";
                    $th4 = "<th>" . "Harga" . "</th>";
                    $th5 = "<th>" . "Hapus Data" . "</th>";
                    echo "<table border=1>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo $th1 ;
                    echo $th2;
                    echo $th3;
                    echo $th4;
                    echo $th5;
                    echo "</tr>";
                    for ($indexo = 0; $indexo < $max; $indexo++) 
                    {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $indexo."</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $_SESSION['chart'][$indexo]['type']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $_SESSION['chart'][$indexo]['idanimal']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .  "Rp. " . $_SESSION['chart'][$indexo]['harga']. ",-"  ."</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . "<a href='deletesession.php?session=$indexo'>" ."Proses ".   "</a>"."</td>";
                    $totalharga += $_SESSION['chart'][$indexo]['harga'];
                    echo "</tr>";
                    }
                    echo "</table>" . "<br/>";
                    echo "<blockquote>" .  "Total Pembelian Item Yang Anda Pesan  =". "<h2>". "Rp." . $totalharga . ",-" ."</h2>" . "</blockquote>";
                    }else
                    {
                        echo "Chart is still Empty";
                    }
                }
```

I've already tried this : 
Suppose that there is a chart already filled by the contents then I tried to delete within this code, I've received error with the unset variable

```
unset($_SESSION['chart'][1])
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried use function `session_unset()`? You can check index of current session and unset it if necessary.

Comment: `unset($_SESSION['chart'][1])` will not work if you refer to the data above. `unset($_SESSION['chart'][0])` should remove the correct index?

Comment: Please refer to the exact answer please, there's an error if I print the data

Comment: Error : Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Comment: A semicolon is missing at the end of the second line : $_SESSION['chart'][0]['index']  = 0

Comment: Which line produce the error? the printdata call ? If so, can you show the code of this function ?

Comment: after line $_SESSION['chart'] = array(); add $_SESSION['chart'][0] = array(); that will remove your notice: Undefined offset: 0

Comment: How to delete the correct session the proper way I mean based on my code, thanks

Comment: Have you set `session_start();` and where you try and delete the session array variable at the top of the page where the function lives? Is this table code example above displaying data?

Comment: Already set, and the question is how to delete it based on my code, please answer to the answer page so I can accept whoever answers this question

Answer (score 0):

I spot several things that could be improved in your code:

- Don't echo in your functions, **return** instead (then echo what the function returns). This gives you more flexibility regarding what you do with your result.
- PHP has a built-in loop for iterating arrays, the **foreach** loop. You should be using that instead of for.

So here's what I have:

```
function print_session_data($session) {
    if (!is_array($session)) {
        return "Array is empty";
    }
    $table_data  = "";
    $total_harga = 0;
    foreach ($session as $index => $data) {
        $table_data .= <<<TABLE_DATA
        <tr>
            <td>$index</td>
            <td>{$data["type"]}</td>
            <td>{$data["idanimal"]}</td>
            <td>Rp. {$data["harga"]}</td>
            <td><a href="deletesession.php?session=$index">Proses</a></td>
        </tr>
TABLE_DATA;
        $total_harga += $data["harga"];

    }

    $result = <<<RESULT
<h3>Berikut abalah keranjang belanja anda</h3>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Animal Type</th>
            <th>ID Binatang</th>
            <th>Harga</th>
            <th>Hapus Data</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        $table_data
    </tbody>
</table>
<blockquote>Total Pembelian Item Yang Anda Pesan = <strong>Rp. $total_harga</strong></blockquote>
RESULT;
    return $result;
}

$_SESSION['chart']                = array();
$_SESSION['chart'][0]['type']     = "Type";
$_SESSION['chart'][0]['idanimal'] = 6;
$_SESSION['chart'][0]['price']    = '$25';
$_SESSION['chart'][0]['harga']    = 25;
echo print_session_data($_SESSION["chart"]); // <== this is the function to print out the data
```

Comment: Wait, there's something deal with the delete session could you show me the code about the delete session within the current index that I wanted to delete, Thanks

Comment: Your code has resulted many errors indeed, have you checked and debugged this yet?

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose that there is a chart already filled by the contents then I
>   tried to delete within this code, I've received error with the unset
>   variable `unset($_SESSION['chart'][1])`

From what I can see from your code the best way to unset the data correctly is as follow:
[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/PFMlSk).

You have to check if the `$_SESSION['chart'][0]` was set before using the session variable index again. If it `$_SESSION['chart']` array still contains other indexes then you can call `printdata();` else indicate that the session was empty.

Comment: Many people have been offering with this but unfortunately there are no straight answers regarding to my question, may answer this question with correct answer that you've tried before, will be appreciating if there's any straight answer rather than post something that I've already declared before. Thanks